# Angular Routerlink is not working and I did everything right

Tags: angular, path, routerlink

```
  <nav>
    <a routerlink="/students"><button mat-stroked-button class="button"><mat-icon class="icon">face</mat-icon><br><br><br>students</button></a>
  </nav>
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'students', component: StudentsComponent},
];
```

angular routerlink don't work. Imported RoutingComponent too app.module etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say you did "everything" right. The [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) directive is case-sensitive.

```
routerLink != routerlink
```

It must be

```html
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/students">
    <button mat-stroked-button class="button">
      <mat-icon class="icon">face</mat-icon><br><br><br>
      students
    </button>
  </a>
</nav>
```